# Linking dropdown lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I would want to link a drop-down list to the values of an adjacent cell. Let say, we have two cells A2 and B2. A2 is a drop-down list with values: Agric, school, sme and housing, while B2, which is also a dropdown list, contains percentages: 30%,20% and 39%, respectively for agric, school and sme & housing such that when I select agric from the dropdown list in A2,  B2 to displays 30% in that order. how do I go about that?

Comment: Hello John it works but when the last value in the dropdown list, that is, housing is selected, 30% instead of 39% shows. Am trying to work on it and to create the table in a different sheet as well. I will play with it and I think it will finally work perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: I updated the answer to use a boolean argument in VLOOKUP as well, which tells Excel to perform an *exact* match. This exact formula should look up your data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup tables were designed for this exact purpose. I would use a drop down list in A2 and a VLOOKUP to a table in B2, since it only makes sense to have one drop-down list. If you want the values of B to be tied to the values of A, it makes sense that you're only going to be selecting the value of A, not both A and B. I would do this:

- In some range of cells, either in a separate, protected sheet or elsewhere in the current sheet, create a lookup table like this. In this example, the table is arbitrarily located in cells H7:I9.

[image: lookup table]

- Highlight the column of the lookup table that contains the categories (agric, school, etc.) and created a named ranged for these categories by clicking **Formulas**, **Name Manager**, **New**. The named range should automatically fill in the "Refers To" field with these cells.
- In cell A2, create the drop-down list by clicking **Data**, **Data Validation**. Under **Allow**, specify **List**, and in the **Source** field, enter `=` and the name of your named range. In the screenshot, I used "categories."

[image: drop down list]

- In cell B2, use `VLOOKUP` to look up the value of A2, which is restricted to the categories in the lookup table, in the columns of the table. This formula works: `=VLOOKUP(A2, $H$7:$I$9, 2, FALSE)`. The `2` indicates that you want the value in the second column of the table, from the row whose first element matches the lookup value (A2). The boolean argument `FALSE` tells Excel to perform an *exact* match. If you enter data in column A that doesn't exist in the table, Excel will return `#N/A`. If you don't enter `FALSE`, Excel will simply return the last item in the table.

Now, the values in A2 are restricted to the categories in the lookup table, and the value in B2 should automatically update according to the respective percentage for that category. If you want to add new categories, simply add them to the lookup table in the same fashion and update the named range.